# MVVM: How to make a function call on a control?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In XAML, I have a TextBox with x:Name of `MyTextBox`.

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox">Some text</TextBox>
```

For speed reasons, I want to call the method `.AppendText`, e.g. In C# code behind, I would call `MyTextBox.AppendText("...")`

However, this is not very MVVM like. If I want to make a call to a function on a control using binding to my ViewModel, what is an elegant way to achieve this?

I'm using MVVM Light.

### Update

I would use the answer from @XAML Lover if I wanted a simple, quick solution. This answer uses a Blend Behavior which is less C# coding.

I would use the answer from @Chris Eelmaa if I wanted write a reusable Dependency Property which I could apply to any TextBox in the future. This example is based on a Dependency Property which, while slightly more complex, is very powerful and reusable once it is written. As it plugs into the native type, there is also slightly less XAML to use it.

Comment: There is no `AppendText` for `TextBlock`.

Comment: Assume `AppendText` is an extension method you create for your `TextBlock`. Then you need to call this on the data bound property `MyText` in your vm, e.g. `<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}" />`.

Comment: @Chris Eelmaa. You're correct, I should have said TextBox. I have corrected the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically when you call a method from a control, it is obvious that you are doing some UI related logic. And that should not sit in ViewModel. But in some exceptional case, I would suggest to create a behavior. Create a **Behavior** and define a DependencyProperty of type **Action<string>** since AppendText should take string as a parameter.

```
public class AppendTextBehavior : Behavior<TextBlock>
{
    public Action<string> AppendTextAction
    {
        get { return (Action<string>)GetValue(AppendTextActionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AppendTextActionProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for AppendTextAction.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AppendTextActionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AppendTextAction", typeof(Action<string>), typeof(AppendTextBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        SetCurrentValue(AppendTextActionProperty, (Action<string>)AssociatedObject.AppendText);
        base.OnAttached();
    }
}
```

In the OnAttached method, I have assigned the extension method that I have created on TextBlock to the DP of Behavior. Now we can attach this behavior to a TextBlock in View.

```
    <TextBlock Text="Original String"
               VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <wpfApplication1:AppendTextBehavior AppendTextAction="{Binding AppendTextAction, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBlock>
```

Consider we have a property in ViewModel with **same signature**. And that property is the source of this binding. Then we can invoke that Action anytime, which will automatically invoke our extension method on TextBlock. Here I am invoking the method on a button click. Remember in this case, our Behavior acts like an Adapter between View and ViewModel.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Action<string> AppendTextAction { get; set; }

    public ICommand ClickCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnClick);
    }

    private void OnClick()
    {
        AppendTextAction.Invoke(" test");
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting approach. Out of curiosity: Is it safe to be called from background or do we have to invoke it from the UI Thread?

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, this answers the question perfectly. The nice thing about this is that it's a one-to-many binding, almost like pub/sub. I can invoke the behaviour in the ViewModel and all Views that are listening can update themselves. In this sense, it's superior to code behind, as we decouple the ViewModel from the View, and we can add another View without altering the existing ViewModel.

Comment: question: what if I want to use this  and have invocation awaitable? I have some code, that is specific to one control and it has some behaviour that is needed to be awaited at some points, but I need to reuse my custom control across several views. Copy pasting code to other VMs or having just sort of decoupled class does not feel like a good options.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a reasonable request to me. `AppendText` is definitely very fast, as it deals with pointers. Pretty much every answer in MVVM world be either subclassing, or attached properties.

You can create new interface, call it `ITextBuffer`:

```
public interface ITextBuffer
{
    void Delete();
    void Delete(int offset, int length);

    void Append(string content);
    void Append(string content, int offset);

    string GetCurrentValue();

    event EventHandler<string> BufferAppendedHandler;
}

internal class MyTextBuffer : ITextBuffer
{
    #region Implementation of ITextBuffer

    private readonly StringBuilder _buffer = new StringBuilder();

    public void Delete()
    {
        _buffer.Clear();
    }

    public void Delete(int offset, int length)
    {
        _buffer.Remove(offset, length);
    }

    public void Append(string content)
    {
        _buffer.Append(content);

        var @event = BufferAppendedHandler;
        if (@event != null)
            @event(this, content);
    }

    public void Append(string content, int offset)
    {
        if (offset == _buffer.Length)
        {
            _buffer.Append(content);
        }
        else
        {
            _buffer.Insert(offset, content);
        }
    }

    public string GetCurrentValue()
    {
        return _buffer.ToString();
    }

    public event EventHandler<string> BufferAppendedHandler;

    #endregion
}
```

This will be used throughout the viewmodels. All you have to do now, is write an attached property that takes advance of such interface, when you do bindings.

Something like this:

```
public sealed class MvvmTextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BufferProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Buffer",
            typeof (ITextBuffer),
            typeof (MvvmTextBox),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(null, PropertyChangedCallback)
        );

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(
        DependencyObject dependencyObject,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs depPropChangedEvArgs)
    {
        // todo: unrelease old buffer.
        var textBox = (TextBox) dependencyObject;
        var textBuffer = (ITextBuffer) depPropChangedEvArgs.NewValue;

        var detectChanges = true;

        textBox.Text = textBuffer.GetCurrentValue();
        textBuffer.BufferAppendedHandler += (sender, appendedText) =>
        {
            detectChanges = false;
            textBox.AppendText(appendedText);
            detectChanges = true;
        };

        // todo unrelease event handlers.
        textBox.TextChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (!detectChanges)
                return;

            foreach (var change in args.Changes)
            {
                if (change.AddedLength > 0)
                {
                    var addedContent = textBox.Text.Substring(
                        change.Offset, change.AddedLength);

                    textBuffer.Append(addedContent, change.Offset);
                }
                else
                {
                    textBuffer.Delete(change.Offset, change.RemovedLength);
                }
            }

            Debug.WriteLine(textBuffer.GetCurrentValue());
        };
    }

    public static void SetBuffer(UIElement element, Boolean value)
    {
        element.SetValue(BufferProperty, value);
    }
    public static ITextBuffer GetBuffer(UIElement element)
    {
        return (ITextBuffer)element.GetValue(BufferProperty);
    }
}
```

The idea here is to wrap `StringBuilder` into an interface (as it raises no events by default :) which can then be exploited by an attached property & `TextBox` actual implementation.

In your viewmodel, you'd probably want something like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ITextBuffer Description { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Description= new MyTextBuffer();

        Description.Append("Just testing out.");
    }
}
```

and in the view:

```
<TextBox wpfApplication2:MvvmTextBox.Buffer="{Binding Description}" />
```

Comment: Brilliant, absolutely brilliant. Thank you for this answer, it solves the problem. I couldn't decide which one to mark as the correct answer, so I went by time. Wish I could mark both of them as answering the question.

Comment: I'll repeat the comments I made on the last answer for your feedback. I think the nice thing about this is that it's a one-to-many binding, almost like pub/sub. I can invoke the behaviour in the ViewModel and all Views that are listening can update themselves. In this sense, it's superior to code behind, as we decouple the ViewModel from the View, and we can add another View without altering the existing ViewModel.

Comment: I really, really like this answer. Binding to an interface solves another problem that I had with persisting/restoring docking layout. This means I can create a single binding, and have two calls on it: one to persist, and one to restore. Absolute genius!

Comment: And your answer even has an event that is raised when anyone else appends text. Very nice.