# Creating control instance in viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, richtextbox, viewmodel

In my program I'm trying to design an output window to display logging information. For right now I'm binding to a string and updating the info as soon as log data comes in.

Ex:

```
<FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph>
        <Run DataContext="{Binding}" Text="{Binding OutputText}"/>
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

(The flow document is inside a rich textbox)

In my viewmodel this is how I'm updating my outputtext

```
OutputText += loggingInfoString;
```

The problem is that strings are immutable data types and I don't like the idea of creating a new string every single time new data comes in. It's an unnecessary overhead.

RichTextBox has a method called AppendText which I assume will use something like a Stringbuilder in order to add to the string. The problem I'm having is being able to access the AppendText in the ViewModel.

I thought about making an instance of RichTextBox inside the ViewModel and binding the RichTextBox to the one in the ViewModel. I'm thinking that this violates MVVM but I'm not entirely sure. Is there another way to go about this? Or should I just create the RichTextBox instance inside the ViewModel?

Ex: 
// ViewModel

```
RichTextBox Output;
```

// Update Method

```
Output.AppendText(loggerInfoText);
```

// Xaml

```
<RichTextBox DataContext="{Binding Output}" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create an interface like so

```
interface IAppender{
    void Append(string appendText);
}
```

You inject this interface into your viewmodel and you implement it in your view.
This means that in your viewmodel code you simply do

```
appender.Append(loggerInfoText);
```

And in your view you implement the interface by adding text to the richtext.
Based on the implementation of your view and viewmodel, depending on where the viewmodel is created you can inject the interface in the viewmodel. Suppose the viewmodel is created in the view you get something like this:

```
class View : UserControl, IAppender{
    View(){
       InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = new YourViewModel(this);
    }
    void Append(string appendText){
        //add text to richttext
    }
}

public class YourViewModel : ViewModelBase{
   private IAppender _appender;
   public YourViewModel(IAppender appender){
       _appender = appender;
   }
}
```

This should get you started I hope
Note that this is pseudo code, not tested not even ran it through a compiler.
Passing the richttext to the viewmodel is indeed not MVVM. The idea is to have separation of concern. Via my interface approach this is not violated.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the swift reply. I can't believe I didn't even think of this. Sometimes as programmers we overlook the simplest of things. Thanks again :)

Comment: I have a quick question. If I have an eventhandler in my viewmodel. Would it be poor practice to add appendtext to the viewmodel's eventhandler?

Comment: Depends on what you mean. Calling Append from the interface that is injected to the viewmodel, and do that in the eventhandler, is not a problem.  The eventhandler itself is not supposed to be attached to a WPF component event. Use commands for that and perhaps even Behaviors. But that is already a bit more advanced MVVM. Hard to see what you need from this end ;-)

Comment: What I meant was inside my MainWindowViewModel I have an EventHandler called UpdateEvent. 

If in my MainWindow (view) I attach an append method to this event handler will that be bad.

Ex: (Pseudo code)

Constructor()
{
     DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
     DataContext.UpdateEvent += Append;
}

void Append(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do appending
}

Comment: The whole idea is to have your dependencies between view and viewmodel through interfaces that can be injected via the constructor of the viewmodel, or via binding. So i would not opt for your eventhandler solution. But eventually it is up to you.

Answer (score -1):

As alternatives to injecting a dependency (which even though decoupled, makes injection of views a pain in the ass) which is implemented by your control:

First, you can use StringBuilder internally to build your string.

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{
    private StringBuilder sb;
    private string Content 
    {
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    protected Append(string text) {
        sb.Append(text);
        PropertyChanged("Content");
    }
}
```

then bind `Content` property to your XAML element. This way you won't have allocations/deallocations in your ViewModel and you don't need to hassle with DI to inject your View/Control into the ViewModel (even though it's abstracted by the interface).

However, this assumes that you are going have avoid this allocations everywhere. If you only want it in a certain type of application (i.e. Windows Store App) but not in your ASP.NET or Desktop app, the second alternative may be much more attractive (especially for other similar scenarios):

You can use a custom Behavior to achieve this, as seen as answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27896179/455493). Behaviors are reusable and you won't have to do this kind of decisions within the ViewModel, allowing you to differently handing this per platform or even per View.

And it simplifies your ViewModel and you won't have to bother how to inject the View that implements the `IAppender` into your ViewModel (can cause troubles in View-first approach, where the View gets resolved by the IoC and which gets the ViewModel injected into the View to be set as DataContext)

Comment: If I use a StringBuilder it's no different than using a string, it would actually be worse. Every time I append the string builder I'll be converting it to a string. So basically I would be appending a string builder then generating a string which is exactly what I wanted to avoid.