# WPF - Best way to initialize Notification Icon without breaking MVVM standards

Tags: c#, mvvm

I am fairly new to the MVVM Architecture, but have developed a handful of applications using MVVM and the Microsoft Community Toolkit Library.

I am currently developing an Event Driven application which monitors various different LogFiles and if an issue is flagged a Custom Notification Icon pops up on the users screen.

I want to abide fully by MVVM Standards, but am struggling to figure out how I could instantiate the Notification User Controls without doing this from a VM.

Due to the fact each Notification User control will look the same, and have the same information within it, I have opted to use one Viewmodel for each Notification Control. This is where the Problem arises.

```
public MainNotifcationViewModel(NotificationHub notiHub, TaskbarIcon tb)
{
    //Taskbar Definition
    _tb = tb;

    //Notification Hub Definition
    _notiHub = notiHub;
    notiHub.NotificationRecieved += NotiHub_NotificationRecieved;
    Debug.WriteLine(notiHub.listOfFileMonitors.Count);
    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<ChangeConfigMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
    {
        GetConfig(m.Value);
    });
}
[RelayCommand]
private async Task GetConfig(Configuration value)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(value);
    _notiHub = new NotificationHub(value);
    //Restart Notification Hub with new Config
}
private void NotiHub_NotificationRecieved(object? sender, Noti.Notification.Hub.Data_Models.Notification.NotificationDetails e)
{
    switch (e.Type)
    {
        case NotiType.Logfile:
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                _tb.ShowCustomBalloon(new LogfileNotification(e), PopupAnimation.Scroll, 5000);
            }));
            break;
    }
}
```

Above, you will see the Viewmodel I have instantiated (within the App.Xaml of my application, instead of as a DataContext, for testing purposes). This Viewmodel Triggers the "Monitoring Part" of my application, which waits for changes to a file, and triggers the `notiHub.NotificationRecieved` Event. This Event then triggers a method, which displays my custom Notification Icon.

I have got this to work Flawlessly by passing in the event details into the `UserControl` via a Constructor (See code below).

```
public partial class LogfileNotification : UserControl
{
    public LogfileNotification(NotificationDetails notiDetails)
    {
        TimeStamp = notiDetails.TimeRecieved.ToLongTimeString();
        NotiType = notiDetails.Type.ToString();
        Message = notiDetails.Message;
        Status = notiDetails.Status.ToString();
        NotiName = notiDetails.Name;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string NotiType { get; set; }
    public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string NotiName { get; set; }
}
```

The UserControl can takes then displays these values within the Notification (by setting it's code behind as the DataContext).

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

The Problem I have with this part of the application, is that is does not abide at all by MVVM Standards. Due to what would be the ViewModel, calling the View.

Has anyone got any ideas on how I could display these Notification `UserControls`, and set a dataContext for them, without breaking any MVVM Standards.

Any Suggestions would be appreciated :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892981/mvvm-how-to-make-a-function-call-on-a-control ... in other words ... you should call `tb.ShowCustomBalloon` on Control side and you need to be able to do this from VM side somehow

Comment: Hey @Selvin, Thankyou for your reply. Sadly, calling the tb.ShowCustomBallon() Method would throw the same issue, as the tb Object would need to be injected into the Control from the ViewModel or App.Xaml code.

Comment: TaskbarIcon can exists without parent control ... you can create it (`new TaskbarIcon {...}`) in some sevice and then inject a service to view model (service contract would have a method to showing balloon)